# what function is running when fill texbox and click Enter Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page it run many script and functions ...
hear i have a textbox , when i click Enter on this it run a function and send message !
I want to know with function Run when I click Enter in this ?
How I can find function orders ?

Comment: Inspect the button, find the selectors (*id, class, parent element etc*), check for event handlers matching the selectors inside the script...

Comment: i try it ! But I cant understand !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the order of function on click event, If you prefer there is a way on debugger of chrome.

After opened the debugger by clicking inspect element , on right side there is a section "mouse panel" at "Event Listener Breakpoint" under "Source Tab", do select an option "click",

**For Add Break Point**

[image]

You have to select click option instead of mouseout in your case.

Now click over the text box, now the program is interrupted with breakpoint, At right side there a panel named "Call Stack", under this option you can see the order of your functions.

**For know order of functions**

[image]

For more information about this feature you can read content at sections

**Pause on Next JavaScript Statement**

**Call Stack panel**

in [Chrome Debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-next-statement)